# Git Can't delete local branch: Operation not permitted

Tags: git, ubuntu, virtualbox

Got below error while trying to Remove the local branch

```
>>> userx@userx-VirtualBox:/media/workspace/project$ git branch -d issue56
error: error replacing .git/packed-refs: Operation not permitted
error: Error deleting branch 'issue56'
```

.git/ Directory persmissions `drwxrwx--- 1 roort vboxsf`

Comment: "Operation not permitted" isn't caused by file permissions, lack of file permissions gives a different error message. But the group `vboxsf` hints this will be a VirtualBox shared folder, which is treated as a separate file system with separate logic as to when operations are permitted which is not always 100% compatible with what regular file systems do. Do you need this working on a shared folder, or would using a VM-local directory also be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes need in shared folder. It's works fine with other shared folder expect `project/`

Comment: Do not do serious work in Virtualbox shared folders. It sometimes works fine, sometimes does not, and sometimes works but is horribly slow. Use them *only* for sharing, i.e., try to treat them as "one side writes, the other side only reads".